# How to import android email source code into eclipse project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I downloaded the android Email app source code [version 2.2] from [**here**](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=tree;h=1428055a409641d909f07d0dbc9d8023fd8da901;hb=9031e67b7e2ec00033a45155ff644fccb33e6bc7). I deleted the .classpath and .project file so that I could import an existing android project. Everything seems to have worked. However, I get quite a few recurring errors such as:

> Attendees cannot be resolved to a
>   variable
>
> android.provider.Calendar cannot be
>   resolved to a variable
>
> Calendar cannot be resolved to a
>   variable

I have set the correct android version `2.2`, what am I missing?

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Since those seems like classes, could you please paste the beginning of the class, I think you forgot a line or two, which makes eclipse to see those as variables.

Comment: I got a snapshot from my above link, so I didn't miss anything out.

Comment: hi Abs i am also facing same issue which jars are i am importing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the included applications cannot(or at least could not) be built with the SDK, as they depend(ed) on non-exported functionality that is only "visible" during the system build.  I'm not sure if Email is still in this category, but it was in the cupcake days.

There are three potential workarounds.  Best is to rewrite those parts of the application to instead use functionality which is exported in the SDK, and thus fairly stable.

Next up is to use reflection to pick up the missing pieces at runtime.

Last is to make do-nothing dummy classes for the needed non-public platform pieces, within your project.  These are enough to let the program compile, and at runtime they get rejected due to name collisions with the hidden system functionality, so you end up utilizing the real classes rather than the dummies.

The proper thing to do is to build the application with the platform build system, rather than the SDK.

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense. Anyone else can confirm?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with Email. I fixed the issue, by adding the following jars into the build path and thus, all the errors were resolved.

```
../out/target/common/obj/APPS/Email_intermediates/classes.jar
../out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar
```

But you need to make the Application build using the platform.

Comment: hi friend Email_intermediates/classes.jar this  file i am not find out please forwrad some solution its urgent

Comment: hi how to download this jars please forward some suggestion