# How can fix issues in Android Email application?

Tags: android, email, smtp, imap

I downloaded the android Email app source code [version 2.2].I deleted the .classpath and .project file so that I could import an existing android project. Everything seems to have worked. However, I get quite a few recurring errors such as:

> Attendees cannot be resolved to a
>   variable
>
> android.provider.Calendar cannot be
>   resolved to a variable
>
> Calendar cannot be resolved to a
>   variable

I have set the correct android version `2.2`, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi,check the build path.You may be missed libraries(path may not set well for android).it may help you.

Comment: hi out/target/common/obj/APPS/Email_intermediates/classes.jar i am search this jar file its not there   how can find this jar file please forward some suggestion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924619/how-to-import-android-email-source-code-into-eclipse-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the imports you have are correct. Sometimes we may get imports from other classes which may not match with Email source.